# 1 billion rows table filtering and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, bigdata

So here is the deal, I have two tables, each has ~ 1B rows. I am trying to query the tables so I can process the data and insert them into other tables. But I don't need to process all ~1B. I only need 10s or 100s of rows to work with each time.

However, the join and the filtering take a long time to return the data.

The tables don't have non-clustered indexes on them but they do have a clustered index on the primary key.

An example of the query:

```sql
select Col1, Col2, Col3 
from 1b_table_1 t1
inner join (
  select * 
  from 1b_table_2 
  where expression=condition
) t2
on t1.join_col = t2.join_col
where CAST(t2.timestamp as date) >= date_var1
and CAST(t2.timestamp as date) <= date_var2
```

**UPDATE**
I tried adding a non-clustered index on 1b_table_1 but the issue I have now is that there is a script running somewhere else that is continuously inserting data into these two tables and I can't create a new index or it will lock the table when building the index and the data write will begin to fail and will cause data loss.

**ANOTHER ONE**

```
SELECT count(*) from 1b_table_1
```

> ~1.2B

```
SELECT count(*) from 1b_table_2
```

> ~22M

```
SELECT count(*) from 1_table_2 where col like condition_string
```

> BEEN RUNNING FOR OVER 5 minutes and no results.
>   The column here is nvarchar(max)!!

Also, I can't change the table structures or indexes on the table.

Comment: Since you have billion-row tables, please provide: 1) What % (avegerage) of rows does `t2.where_col1 = where_exp1` select by itself? 2) What % (avegerage) of rows does `t2.where_col2 = where_exp2` select by itself? 3) What % (avegerage) of rows does `where expression=condition` select by itself? 4) What tables do the columns `Col1, Col2, Col3` belong to?

Comment: Remember that non-clustered indexes suffer from the "dual-index seek" syndrome. Shouldn't be a severe issue if you are walking hundreds of rows only.

Comment: Depending on your SQL edition, you might be able to create the index with `ONLINE=ON` option to avoid locking the table for the duration of the create.

Comment: @nael 1) Are pre-computations suitable for you? I.e. materialized view for `SELECT count(*) from 1_table_2 where col like condition_string`? Or event pre-compute the whole query, if data freshness is not very critical. 2) Is that possible to add columnstore indexes? Looks like you're trying OLAP queries over OLTP database. With that number of rows, I suppose you can benefit a lot from VertiPaq complession, and from ability to query/read only separate columns. 3) Which performance you're trying to achive? How often the query is run? Which hardware?

Comment: Perhaps explain why you think you need to cast t2.timestamp to date. Perhaps [this discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) of casting to date vs. sargability is useful.

Comment: And you specifically state that you "can't change ... indexes on the table" yet you went down this path. So ... which is it?

Answer (score 1):

First, the subquery is unnecessary.  You can write the query as:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 
from 1b_table_1 t1 join
     1b_table_2 t2
     on t1.join_col = t2.join_col
where t2.expression = t2.condition and
      t2.where_col1 = where_exp1 and
      t2.where_col2 = where_exp2;
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on:

- `1b_table_2(where_col1, where_col2, + columns in the "expression", join_col)`
- `1b_table_1(join_col)`.

Comment: As a general approach, yes, this is much better than the starting point of the OP. However, with that amount of data, prolly more optimization may be needed.